# a adjective meaning sufficient, more than enough

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for an adjective meaning sufficient, more than enough in the following sentence.

I have a _____hour to get there.

I want to suggest in this word that an hour is more than enough for me to get there.

I was thinking **a full hour**. But it sort of lacks the connotation I am looking for.

Is there a better fit?

Thanks.

Comment: I would use **a good hour**, implying 'approximately an hour, probably more'.

Comment: "good" sounds simple and accurate. Thanks, @KateBunting

Comment: It's arguable that the usage here (a good hour) is quantifier rather than adjective, if meaning is still allowed to influence word-class, as some linguists believe. 'A good hour' = 'One and a bit hours'. 'Good' here says nothing about a notional 60-minute timespan per se.  At the very least, it's a very peripheral adjective.

Comment: What's wrong with *sufficient* itself? Why can it not be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in:

I have an **ample** hour to get there.  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ample)

> 2. Fully sufficient to meet a need or purpose:

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

> **adequate**

which means reasonably sufficient specially when you are talking about quality.

*merriam-webster's example*: **adequate time**

Comment: Hello, Mehdi. Certainly right ball-park, but doesn't fit into OP's sample sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Will you do me a favour by sending an email to me saying that 'what you think about that purpose', I would become thankful, leaksin@gmail.com

Comment: You believe we've been put here for purpose...

Comment: Broadly, to worship God and live as He recommends / advises / orders. More specifically, as outlined in the NT, and directed on a daily basis by the Holy Spirit. But as James says, 'We all make many mistakes'.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but I expected something more philosophical as the of 'purpose'

Comment: Philosophy is not wrong per se, but the original sin was essentially man deciding (and acting upon the decision) that he, rather than God, was equipped to be and had the authority to be the final arbiter of right (good) and wrong (evil). Philosophy is usually a sophisticated way of denying God.

Comment: By the way, you have your own view, and you are Okay with that, I guess Philosophy has been trying to reason about every thing, it's quit pessimistic if you say so.